# Function type in javascript

Tags: javascript, types

I want to create my own signal emitter or callback storage, call it whatever you want.

Here is what I come up so far:

```
var DetonationCallback = function detonationCallback() {
    detonationCallback.callbacks = [];
    detonationCallback.add = function(callback) {
        detonationCallback.callbacks.push(callback);
    };
    for(var i = 0; i < detonationCallback.callbacks.length; ++i) {
        callback[i](arguments);
    }
};
```

Basically I have two problems now which I can not tackle. The first one is how can I move

```
    detonationCallback.callbacks = [];
    detonationCallback.add = function(callback) {
        detonationCallback.callbacks.push(callback);
    };
```

outside of the function? And another question is how can I pass all the arguments which were passed into the `detonationCallback` just in the same order into `callback[i]`?

Will be grateful for any answer.

Additional info: when done with the implementation of the type I would like to use it as follows:

```
var callback = new DetonationCallback();

function f1() {

}

function f2(firstArg, secondArg) {

}

callback.add(f1);
callback.add(f2);

callback();
```

Comment: You can't really do this with the `new` keyword. The `new` keyword returns a new instance of `DetonationCalback`. You can't `return` anything if you're calling a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make detonationCallback an Object

```
var detonationCallbacks = {};
detonationCallbacks.callbacks = [];
detonationCallback.clear = function() {
    detonationCallback.callbacks = [];
}
detonationCallback.add = function(callback) {
    detonationCallback.callbacks.push(callback);
};
```

Second, make your detonate a function in detonationCallback

```
detonationCallback.detonate = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < detonationCallback.callbacks.length; ++i) {
        this.callback[i](arguments);
    }
};
```

If you want/need to use new, just create an object prototype for this

Comment: Sounds good. But I still have a problem with passing parameters into `callback[i]`.

Comment: @yrslvrtfmv you can just use `arguments`: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript_tutorials/varargs.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wan't to move the add function outside but how about using a class instead?

Also note the use of [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to send several arguments with an array.

```js
class DetonationCallback {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = [];
    }
      
    add(callback) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
    }
      
    call(args) {
        this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
        });
    }
}

var callback = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

var callback2 = function(arg1) {
    console.log(arg1);
}

var handler = new DetonationCallback();

handler.add(callback);
handler.add(callback2);
handler.call(['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write this yourself:

When using node you can use the built in EventEmitter lib.
https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

There is also a port for the Browser
https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter